# Node Security service shutdown: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.nodesecurity.io

Tags: node.js, security, npm

The Node Security Platform service has been depreciated since 30 September this year. I have been continuing using the [NSP package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nsp) until it finally failed today. I'd like to document the error in public so others can find it later.

The error I got today:

> Error: Client request error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.nodesecurity.io api.nodesecurity.io:443

```
> eslint . && nsp check

(+) Error: Client request error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.nodesecurity.io api.nodesecurity.io:443
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! htm-gateway@1.0.1 lint: `eslint . && nsp check`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the project@1.0.1 lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> "beginning with npm@6, a new command, [npm audit](https://medium.com/npm-inc/announcing-npm-6-5d0b1799a905), recursively analyzes
>   your dependency trees to identify specifically what’s insecure,
>   recommend a replacement, or fix it automatically with `npm audit fix`."

Hence, updating

```
nsp check
```

to

```
npm audit --audit-level high
```

Other configurations and options can be found [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/audit)

**Note that  `--audit-level high` flag might only work for NPM version > v6.4.0 (read [v6.4.0-next.0 commits](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/176793894570/v640-next0))**

Configurable audit level for non-zero exit npm audit currently exits with exit code 1 if any vulnerabilities are found of any level. Added a flag of `--audit-level` to `npm audit` to allow it to pass if only vulnerabilities below a certain level are found.

Example: `npm audit --audit-level=high` will exit with 0 if only low or moderate level vulns are detected.

---

NPM Docs: https://docs.npmjs.com/auditing-package-dependencies-for-security-vulnerabilities

Official blog: https://blog.npmjs.org/post/175511531085/the-node-security-platform-service-is-shutting

---

> **Updates about ignoring security advisory**

There are NPM packages made available to extend features of the new `npm-audit` command (like ignoring certain advisories), for examples:

- [audit-filter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/audit-filter)
- [better-npm-audit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-npm-audit) (couldn't get the above package working, so created this package myself)